# MySQL query, checking for single vs double digits

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my client-provided database that has values such as '2; 3; 14' or '1', etc. I am using MySQL.  How do I write the query so that

1) I can check if the column contains a number (1, for example)
2) I won't get a 'hit' if I am checking for a '1' and the value is actually '14', for example.

Thanks is advance

Comment: Is it a numeric column or varchar?

Comment: varchar, with values delimited by colons

Answer (score 0):

If column is varchar and you want to return row while searching for '1' in '1;3;14' then you can use REGEXP operator for regular expression search with [**word boundary character**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) .

```
select * from test
where col regexp '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
```

[**SQL FIddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/109f1/14)

**From MySQL docs**

```
Word Boundary Markers [[:<:]], [[:>:]]

These markers stand for word boundaries. 
They match the beginning and end of words, respectively. 
A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters.
A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore (_).

mysql> SELECT 'a word a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';   -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'a xword a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';  -> 0
```

Comment: But I want to return a FALSE if I am searching for '1' and the value is '14'.

Comment: suppose column value is '1;23;40'  . should it return false ?

Comment: No, TRUE, because the value specifically includes a '1', vs '21' or '13'.

Comment: Also using php with this.  Possible to turn the string into an array using ';' as a delimiter and then do a 'for each' loop against each value in the array?

Comment: use php explode() function for that

Comment: Hmmm, not as easy as I thought.  Here's what I have so far, which works great for single values

$query = (Start of Query...);

$RelevantSegmentPieces = explode(",",$RelevantSegment);
foreach($RelevantSegmentPieces as $key){
  $query = $query . "brad.RelevantSegment = " . $key . " OR ";
}

$query = $query . "brad.RelevantSegment = 999) ";
$query = $query . (End of Query...);

How to pull the value of the row when I am still building the query???

Comment: A bit of a hack, but I only have possible values of 1 - 15, or a combination of the values such as '2;13', etc. Possible to craft the query to return true for 'contains 1', but not 1 followed by 2 (12), etc?